# How to detect if malware is packed or not?

Tags: static, analysis, malware

I have an executable which has been identified as wannacry ransomware. I want to know how you can find out if it is packed or not. I have used the tool Exeinfo and found that its written in microsoft visual c++ etc

Please could someone tell how to verify if it is packed or not[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could analyse the file using PEiD, if it has been packed often PEiD will give the name of the packer used.

You could also open the exe in PEView and check `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER code`, if there is a large difference between the virtual size and size of the raw data that's another indicator that the exe was packed.